# How to specialize documenters in sphinx autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am documenting a project with Sphinx I want to create a specialized version of the `autoclass::` directive that allows me to modify the documentation string for certain classes.

Here is one thing I have tried: searching the sphinx source, I found that the `autoclass` directive is created via the [`ClassDocumenter` object](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py#L1216). Following this, my idea was to register a subclass of `ClassDocumenter` for the classes of interest, and then override `get_doc` to modify the docstring.

Here's my attempt at such an extension:

```
from six import class_types
from sphinx.ext.autodoc import ClassDocumenter
from testmodule import Foo  # the class that needs modified documentation


class MyClassDocumenter(ClassDocumenter):
    objtype = 'myclass'
    priority = 20  # higher priority than ClassDocumenter

    @classmethod
    def can_document_member(cls, member, membername, isattr, parent):
        return isinstance(member, class_types) and issubclass(member, Foo)

    def get_doc(self, encoding=None, ignore=1):
        doc = super(MyClassDocumenter, self).get_doc(encoding, ignore)
        # do something to modify the output documentation
        doc[0].insert(0, "ADD SOMETHING TO THE DOC")
        return doc

def setup(app):
    app.add_autodocumenter(MyClassDocumenter)
```

The problem is, when I run this I get an error: `ERROR: Unknown directive type "py:myclass".` It seems that registering a documenter is not enough to register the associated directive, but I've not been able to find any clues in the sphinx source to tell me how such a registration is supposed to happen. It's not as simple as using the standard `add_directive()` methods, because I have no explicit directive to register.

How can I correctly accomplish such a specialization of an auto-documenter in sphinx?

(note: the full set of files to reproduce the error is available [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jakevdp/34a57475bce1bf210667630aa622f407))

Comment: To modify the docstring it might be easier to use the `autodoc-process-docstring` event. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-docstring.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn, that looks very promising! I'll give that approach a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have found something in [Docutils markup API](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/markupapi.html#directives)

> Directives are handled by classes derived from docutils.parsers.rst.Directive. They have to be registered by an extension using Sphinx.add_directive() or Sphinx.add_directive_to_domain().

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. That doesn't really help – I know how to register new directives. What I'm unclear on is how sphinx autodoc does this internally for the various directives created by Documenter subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

`Documenter` classes require an existing directive to apply, when appropriate. This can either be a "built in" directive, or it can be a custom directive you create and register. Either way, the directive to use is specified by the `directivetype` class attribute. You can specify this value explicitly:

```
class MyClassDocumenter(ClassDocumenter):
    directivetype = 'foo' # corresponds to :foo: in the doc source
    objtype = 'bar'
    priority = 20
```

Or, it looks like you can omit `directivetype` and it will use the same value as `objtype` by default. (This is an educated guess)

So then the question is: have you registered a new directive for `:myclass:`? If not I think that is the problem. Alternatively, if there is some other directive that you want to be used (whether built-in, or custom) the answer is probably to specify it explicitly by including a value for `directivetype` in your `Documenter` class definition.

Comment: Thanks for the response – that makes sense, but what I really want is to inherit and modify what happens in ``autoclass``. Unless I'm mistaken, that diretive is not explicitly defined anywhere, but is implicitly created via the ``ClassDocumenter``. Am I wrong on that? If so, where is the ``autoclass`` directive defined, so that I can inherit from it and extend it in order to define the ``myclass`` directive?

Comment: OK, but do you want to modify it by using the existing `:class:` directive as-is but having the documenter do something different "at a higher level"? Or do you want to customize the `:class:` directive itself?  If the former, I think you just need `directivetype = 'class'`. If the latter, the python domain `:class:` directive is defined here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/domains/python.py#L317-L339

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to answer that. Maybe I should rephrase: all I want is a means to capture the output of whatever is happening in ``:autoclass:``, to modify it for certain objects, and to pass it back to the autodoc process. From @mzjn's comment above, it looks like maybe an event hook is a better approach than going down this Documenter/Directive specialization rabbit-hole.

Comment: My experience led me to the observation that (once you wrap your head around things) its usually simple to create a new `Documenter`, *in the case you are doing so for a new custom directive*. The new directive might be complicated, or not, but creating a `Documenter` for it is typically not much code. But it sounds like you want to tweak existing behavior, which is probably often easier with event hooks. The reason for this is probably because with a custom directive, you know exactly what it is and does. Overriding existing ones leaves alot of questions about what to override and where.